# word problems questions

Tags: word-problem

An army contingent has 9820 men in total. They are required to stand for inspection in equal number of rows and columns. Find the number of man in each row and columns. How many man are left out ?

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: As pointed out by peterwhy's sarcastic answer, your question is missing a very important clarification... presumably that *as many men as possible will stand for inspection*.  As for an approach, consider the use of the square root function and the floor function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one row and one column, so $9819$ men are left out.

Comment: 0 rows and 0 columns, 9820 men are left out.

Answer (score 3):

The largest square which is less than $9820$ is $99^2=9801$, so there are 19 men left out.